# How to get credentials for Plaid Development(Free access to live accounts for testing)?

Tags: plaid

Plaid says when building in development mode We will have Free access to live accounts for testing -- does that mean we will get those live account credentials for testing in plaid Development environment(like we get for sandbox environment-user_good, pass_good).If yes how to get them(support ticket?, from settings? etc).

Or do we need to use real life credentials for testing in development environment. I am not sure how this works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the latter -- when testing in Development, you test with real life credentials.  That's the difference between Development and Sandbox -- Sandbox has test data and test accounts, while Development lets you test with real data and real accounts.